# Set a default value on transaction rollback in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, rollback

Is it possible to set a table row field to some default value in case a transaction were rolled back?

Consider a scenario where for each row in a table a task is run, which should modify a `state` field according to the actual task state. So first the task would update the row with `state=running`, then it would begin a transaction, do some processing and update the row with `state=complete`. When the processing is done, the task commits the transaction and the `complete` state becomes visible. However, if the task abruptly fails (imagine power failure), the transaction would roll back and the state remained `running` for ever. Is it possible to set a default value like `failed` that would be used in such case?

I'm specifically interested in doing this in Postgres, but I'd gladly learn if that's possible in any database, or what else can be done to achieve such effect.

**EDIT:**

In other words, I need to make 2 concurrent, mutually exclusive transactions, so that if one fails, then the other is committed. Alternatively, it can be thought of as a two-stage transaction with a persistent savepoint.

Comment: Why not set the state _inside_ the transaction?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what state?

Comment: What you mention: `state=running`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name and how would that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can use is savepoints:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SAVEPOINT a;

/* do some work */

UPDATE atable SET state = 'complete' WHERE ...;

COMMIT;
```

Now if there is an error, you catch that error and perform

```
ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT a;

UPDATE atable SET state = 'failed' WHERE ...;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: but the whole question is about failures that cannot be handled by software, like power outage :) I would need something like a persistent savepoint, _before_ which I could set state=failed

Comment: That cannot be, because in the case of a crash or power outage on the database, who should magically change the state? You'd have to find a software solution, like an expiry timestamp after which a state of `running` is implicitly understood as `failed`.

Comment: Well, if a transaction can rollback itself, why couldn't it revert to the last "persistent savepoint" instead of reverting the whole transaction? Technically it should be achievable, and I hoped the solution to this problem already exists.

Comment: No, that cannot be. A savepoint (subtransaction) is always part of the main transaction, so if the main transaction is not committed, the subtransaction cannot be. And there is no feature to commit a transaction if the session is interrupted; that would be bad. What is the problem with the idea from my previous comment?

Comment: The problem is that your solution is obvious, but unreliable. You cannot "catch" an error if there's no error but a power outage or hardware failure, so the state may remain `running` forever.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. You have one column `state` and a second column `state_changed` of type `timestamp with time zone`. Then you query like this: `SELECT CASE WHEN state_changed < current_timestamp - INTERVAL '1 minute' AND state = 'running' THEN 'failed' ELSE state END`.